# fail2ban ban multiply recidive hosts

Tags: linux, security, fail2ban

We are using fail2ban on our web-facing servers to block IP addresses that repeatedly fail to authenticate properly. Our normal bantime hereby is one hour; IPs that have already been banned multiple times are blocked for a day using the `recidive` jail included in the fail2ban example config.

This block duration of one day was chosen in order not to affect dynamic IPs too much, especially considering the `recursive` jail does not block specific ports, but all incoming connections. However, we would like to ban very persistent attackers for a longer period of time. Currently, this is achieved by a custom `super-recidive` filter and jail. This jail blocks for a whole week every host which has been banned by `recidive` twice (this IP is obviously not dynamically assigned).

Ideally however, I would like to ban for a week every IP which has been banned by `recidive` in the past (say, one week) and which after being unbanned is banned again by whatever jail. I know something like this must be possible with a complex `failregex` including backreferences - but is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking in to a more robust Web Application Firewall, like NGINX. You can pass repeat offenders to your NGINX blacklist where there could be a different set of rules for how long an offender is blocked.

EXAMPLE:
https://www.nginx.com/blog/dynamic-ip-blacklisting-with-nginx-plus-and-fail2ban/